# Dropdown List is not getting the CSS in asp.net

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I am trying to make a DROPDOWN list from [this](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_filter) tutorial. The functions seem to work very good, but it doesnt get the CSS.

this is what it looks.
[image: img1]

Since the  refreshes the page when its pressed. I tried to add it as a  but still the same problem, the CSS does not get implemented.

any suggestion?

this is the snipped code:

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
#myInput {
    border-box: box-sizing;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 14px 12px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
    border: none;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 230px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Whats the problem here? I cant figure it out.

Comment: Looks good to me... snipet works fine.

Comment: Your snippet appears to work in latest versions of chrome, firefox and ie and look nothing like your image.

Comment: yea, and thats what I am not understanding. the css code is inside the same file where all other designs.. it just doesnt work. I force refreshed the page. 

its impossible to figure this out for me! maybe is the ASP.net problem?

Comment: even tho CSS file is imported. it reads only a few of the CSS classes.. not all of them.. how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using web forms or mvc asp.net? Use developer tools in chrome (f12) to inspect the elements and see what classes are applied and what are be overridden (you can also use firebug for firefox). It could be an issue with [Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). Also check for syntax errors in you CSS which could be invalidating the classes not being applied.

Comment: Does your css is in different file? if so, are you including it in your head tag  ?

Comment: If separate css file were used instead of placing styles in the same file as HTML markups, try adding `<link href="[path to css file]" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` inside head tag. If the path is incorrect and still can't get CSS styles loaded, use relative path e.g. `href="~/Content/css/style.css"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe problem of css in separate file, that in line
.dropdown a:hover
after background-color property value missing semicolon?